# How is the Odds Shark "Predicted Score" calculated?

Tags: betting

I was looking for some statistics for research reasons on past game history and stumbled upon "Predicted Score". Then, I decided to try to figure out how this statistic is being calculated and could not find any search for the answer, and it brought me here.

In this case: "Predicted Score (65.2 - 78.4)" where the 65.2 is the current spread favorite at -1.5.

So my questions are:

1. How is this number being calculated? A computer using stats, experts, ratio of bets placed?
2. Would that mean the favorite is actually a 13.2 point underdog?